# looping in python for getting table names

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
tablename1 = GetTbname(1)
tablename2 = GetTbname(2)
tablename3 = GetTbname(3)
.
.
.
.
tablenamen = GetTbname(n)
print(tablename1)
print(tablename2)
print(tablename3)
.
.
.
.
print(tablenamen)
```

How do I print the above one in looping format so that I can just enter `tablename = GetTbname` to get the entire table instead of typing entirely manually.

Comment: Use `range` function `for i in range(1, n): ....`

Comment: Put your table names into a list instead of separate variables.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a loop and store the names in a list:

```
num_tables = 100 # or any other value
tables = []

for i in range(num_tables):
    tables.append(GetTbname(i + 1))

for table in tables:
    print(table)
```

Comment: *`tables.append(GetTbname(i + 1))`

Comment: @VineethSai erg, yeah. Stupid typo, thanks for noticing. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(n):
   print(GetTbname(i))
```

In the code above, I assumed there is a list and the `GetTbname` function returns something based on the index from this list. Here `n` is the length of the list. I started the loop from `0`. You can use `range(1,n)` to start from `1`.

Comment: Wheres the explanation?

Comment: I assumed there is a list and the GetTbname function returns something based on the index from this list. here 'n' is the length of the list. Here i started the loop from 0. You can use range(1,n) to start from 1.